# Apache Notice/Error For Django Website

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-web-services

For the last two months, I've been seeing this set of errors in my logs.

```
[core:notice] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[mpm_prefork:notice] AH00173: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[so:warn] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[auth_digest:notice] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[mpm_prefork:notice] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal
```

Once in a while, I'll also see this before the **SIGHUP received** line.

```
[cgi:error] AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php
```

These set of notices/errors occur **1-3 times per day**. I'm not very familiar with Apache, could anyone tell me what these messages mean and how I may fix the issue.

Some additional information: I'm running the website with Django 1.8 using AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Amazon Linux).

Answer (score 0):

The message:

```
[so:warn] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
```

means you have `LoadModule` directive for `wsgi_module` appearing more than once in your Apache configuration files. Likely you have added it to a site file when it is already found in a configuration file related to the module.

The message:

```
[cgi:error] AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/php
```

means you likely have a global `AddHandler`, `AddFilter` or similar for mapping any request for a resource with `.php` extension to PHP. When done as a filter in particular, that can trigger for any request ending in `.php` even though you are only running a Django site. The requests for `.php` files will turn up as people are probing your site for PHP vulnerabilities. You should find the PHP configuration and comment it out.

No idea about `mod_heartmonitor` message but never seen it cause an issue.

Only other thing can see wrong is that you are using an ancient version of mod_wsgi. Version 3.5 is effectively a version from five years ago and is over 50 versions behind. You shouldn't use such an old version of mod_wsgi. It is not supported by anyone.